# Kotlin Extension Functions - Override existing method

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

is it possible to do something like:

```
/**
 * Converts all of the characters in the string to upper case.
 *
 * @param str the string to be converted to uppercase
 * @return the string converted to uppercase or empty string if the input was null
 */
fun String?.toUpperCase(): String = this?.toUpperCase() ?: ""
```

- What would this do?  It would make `toUpperCase` null safe.
- What problem am I having? the return value, `this?.toUpperCase()`,
  refers to the extension function

**Is the only option to rename my extension function or is there a way to refer to the "super" function from within it?**

Comment: Assuming there were a way to achieve this, it would be ambiguous, right?  If I do `"foo".toUpperCase()` which method would get called?

Comment: I would assume the extension function.... but I hadn't considered that until now

Comment: What I mean is, `toUpperCase` is already an extension method in Kotlin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot override an existing member function.

> If a class has a member function, and an extension function is defined
>   which has the same receiver type, the same name is applicable to given
>   arguments, the member always wins.

[source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically)

> Is the only option to rename my extension function or is there a way to refer to the "super" function from within it?

You will have to rename your extension function and call the member function you want to use from within.

Answer (score 11):

The [source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#nullable-receiver) as [pau1adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6229448/pau1adam) cites actually only says the member wins out when a member is applicable. That means defining an extension function `toUpperCase()` for the nullable type `String?` is totally valid.

- When calling `toUpperCase()` on a non-null `String`, the member function is called.
- When calling `toUpperCase()` on a nullable `String?`, there is no member function. Thus the extension function is called.

The safe call operator `?.` actually autocasts `this` to the non-null `String` type, so the function you defined does exactly what you want it to.

You can find more details at the [source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#nullable-receiver), where they explain how `Any?.toString()` could be implemented.